Level-set submanifold is symplectic iff Poisson bracket matrix is nonsingular

Let $M$ be a symplectic manifold, $\Psi=(\psi^1,\ldots,\psi^k):M\to \mathbb{R}^{k}$ a smooth map, and $c$ a regular value. Consider a submanifold $N=\Psi^{-1}(c)\hookrightarrow M$.
Show that $N$ is symplectic if and only if the matrix $(c^{ij})$, with $c^{ij}=\{\psi^i,\psi^j\}$, is invertible for all $x\in N$.

In class we saw that in local coordinates $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ the canonical isomorphism $\omega^\sharp:T^*M\to TM$ is represented by the matrix with entries $\{x_i,x_j\}$.
Since $N$ is a level-set submanifold, for any coordinate system $x_1,\ldots,x_{2n}$ of $M$, we can substitute the first $k$ coordinates with the functions $\psi^1,\ldots,\psi^k$ to obtain an "adapted chart" for $N$. (I read Tu, Intro. to manifolds for the Regular Level-set theorem).
The matrix of $\omega^\sharp$ looks like this, it is composed of four clearly different blocks:
$\begin{pmatrix} \{\psi^1,\psi^1\} &\cdots &\{\psi^k,\psi^1\} &\{x^{k+1},\psi^1\} &\cdots &\{x^{2n},\psi^1\}\\
 \vdots &&\vdots &&&\vdots\\
\{\psi^1,\psi^k\} &\cdots &\{\psi^k,\psi^k\} &\{x^{k+1},\psi^k\} &\cdots &\{x^{2n},\psi^k\}\\
 \{\psi^1,x^{k+1}\} &\cdots &\{\psi^k,x^{k+1}\} &\{x^{k+1},x^{k+1}\} &\cdots &\{x^{2n},x^{k+1}\} \\
 \vdots &&\vdots &&&\vdots\\
 \{\psi^1,x^{2n}\} &\cdots &\{\psi^k,x^{2n}\} &\{x^{k+1},x^{2n}\} &\cdots &\{x^{2n},x^{2n}\}
\end{pmatrix}$
And the matrix for $\omega^\sharp_N$ is the lower-right block. When restricting to $N$, the upper-right and lower-left blocks are zero since $\psi$ is constant on $N$.
The determinant of that big matrix must be non-zero because $M$ is symplectic, and it equals the product of the upper-left and lower right blocks. This means that if the upper left matrix (called $(c^{ij})$ is nonsingular, the lower right matrix (I called this $\omega^\sharp_N$) must be nonsingular as well. But if $(c^{ij})$ is singular, the $\omega^\sharp_N$ is not obliged to be singular.
I'm sure there's a flaw in this argument (also because if $k=n$ and we take Darboux coordinates, $\omega^\sharp_N$ is just zero...)

A problem with your argument is that it is not for any coordinate system $x_1, \dots, x_{2n}$ of $M$ that we can substitute the first $k$ coordinates with the functions $\psi^1, \dots, \psi^k$ and obtain a new chart for $M$. Indeed, imagine for instance that $N$ what determined by the last $k$ coordinates $x_j$ being zero, e.g. take $\psi^j = x_{2n+1-j}$ for $1 \le j \le k$ and $c = 0$. Then  replacing $x_1, \dots, x_k$ by $\psi^1, \dots, \psi^k$ does not yield a chart for $M$.

EDIT: My initial answer was incorrect. The following argument seems simpler and more orthodox.
Let $N = \Psi^{-1}(c)$ for some regular value $c$ of $\Psi$. Then the 1-forms $d\psi^1, \dots, d\psi^k$ are linearly independent at each point $m \in N$. Using $\omega^{\sharp}$, these $1$-forms correspond to the Hamiltonian vector fields $X_1, \dots, X_k$, and these are linearly independent along $N$.
Let $V_m \subset T_m M$ be the vector subspace spanned by $X_1, \dots, X_k$ at $m$. For $m \in N$, $V_m$ is the symplectic orthogonal to $T_m N$: $V_m$ certainly belongs to the symplectic orthogonal to $T_m N$, and $V_m$ has dimension $k$ equal to the codimension of $T_m N$, hence it must equal the symplectic orthogonal to $T_m N$.
It is a well-known fact that a subspace $A$ of a symplectic space is symplectic if and only if its symplectic orthogonal is symplectic. In our context, this means that $T_m N$ is symplectic if and only if $V_m$ is symplectic (for $m \in N$).
Finally, up to a sign convention, the matrix $(c^{ij})$ is given by
$$c^{ij} := \{ \psi^i, \psi^j\}(m) = \omega_m(X_i(m), X_j(m)). $$
Hence, for $m \in N$, this matrix is nonsingular precisely when $V_m$ is symplectic, thus precisely when $T_m N$ is symplectic.

Thank you so much! I hope these questions aren't too silly:


Is it true that the strategy is to use that, in general, a form $\eta:TX\times TX\to\mathbb{R}$ is nondegenerate iff $\pi_\eta:T^*X\times T^*X\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $(\alpha,\beta)\mapsto\eta(\eta^\sharp\alpha,\eta^\sharp\beta)$ is nondegenerate?


This allows us to work on the cotangent bundle of the submanifold, where the conormal bundle $\mathsf{N}N$ is defined. But, is it always true that $T_m^*M\cong\mathsf{N}_mN\oplus T_m^*N$? Looks like this decomposition works for symplectic submanifolds.




Then, is it true that a form on a vector space $X\oplus Y$ is nondegenerate iff it is nondegenerate on any of the components?


@danimalabares (edited comment) You are right, my answer is not quite correct (because $\iota^\pi$ is ill-defined). I'll try to correct my answer as soon as possible. In the meantime: 1. Yes, since $\eta^{\sharp}$ is then a bundle isomorphism. 3. It is false, since $X$ and $Y$ could be Lagrangians. 2. This decomposition is general. If you use coordinates $y_1, \dots, y_{2n}$ on $M$ such that $N$ is the locus where the last $k$ $y_j$s vanish, then the first $2n-k$ $dy_j$s span $T^_m N$ and the last $k$ $dy_j$s span $\mathsf{N}_m N$.
